# How do I remove a duplicate record in output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this query:

```
select o.customers_customer_id, oi.product_product_id, oi.quantity, o.order_date
from orders o
join order_item oi on oi.ORDERS_ORDER_ID=o.ORDER_ID
where o.ORDER_DATE ='12/31/2015';
```

It returns 8 records, however, one customer id appears twice.

Output:

```
EH-14185    OFF-PA-10002421 4   12/31/2015
JP-16135    OFF-ST-10001526 4   12/31/2015
JP-16135    OFF-BI-10002194 1   12/31/2015
KD-16495    OFF-BI-10004654 6   12/31/2015
BM-11785    OFF-LA-10003720 2   12/31/2015
BD-11605    FUR-CH-10000454 1   12/31/2015
CJ-11875    OFF-AR-10004269 5   12/31/2015
BM-11785    OFF-SU-10001664 2   12/31/2015
```

`distinct` doesn't work

The query is based on 2 tables: `orders` and `order_item`

orders table

```
Name                  Null     Type         
--------------------- -------- ------------ 
ORDER_ID              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
ORDER_DATE                     VARCHAR2(30) 
CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMER_ID NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

order_item table

```
Name                 Null     Type         
-------------------- -------- ------------ 
QUANTITY                      VARCHAR2(30) 
LINE_ITEM_SALE_PRICE          VARCHAR2(19) 
ORDERS_ORDER_ID      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

I tried distinct on the customers_customer_id column

```sql
select o.customers_customer_id, oi.product_product_id, oi.quantity, o.order_date
from orders o
join order_item oi on oi.ORDERS_ORDER_ID=o.ORDER_ID
where o.ORDER_DATE ='12/31/2015' ;
```

```
EH-14185    OFF-PA-10002421 4   12/31/2015
JP-16135    OFF-ST-10001526 4   12/31/2015
KD-16495    OFF-BI-10004654 6   12/31/2015
BM-11785    OFF-LA-10003720 2   12/31/2015
BD-11605    FUR-CH-10000454 1   12/31/2015
CJ-11875    OFF-AR-10004269 5   12/31/2015
BM-11785    OFF-SU-10001664 2   12/31/2015
```

Comment: I don't see a DISTINCT in any of your queries presented. Also, my guess is this is because one order has multiple lines for the same order id, and as the customer places the order, the customer id shows up multiple times. This is expected behavior. What would you expect to be the results in this situation? You either show the duplicated (header) information, or you don't. That's about all you can do - 2 order lines = 2 rows

Comment: do you have any criteria about which of the records should be selected when duplicate value for `customers_customer_id` met ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with those "duplicates". One option, if you don't care about the rest of values, is to aggregate them, e.g.

```
select o.customers_customer_id, 
       max(oi.product_product_id) product_id, 
       max(oi.quantity) quantity, 
       max(o.order_date) order_date
from orders o
join order_item oi on oi.ORDERS_ORDER_ID=o.ORDER_ID
where o.ORDER_DATE ='12/31/2015'
group by c.customers_customer_id;
```

Comment: Union of *what* with *what*? Try and see; I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a DISTINCT in any of your queries presented. Also, my guess is this is because one order has multiple lines for the same order id, and as the customer places the order, the customer id shows up multiple times. This is expected behavior. What would you expect to be the results in this situation? You either show the duplicated (header) information, or you don't. That's about all you can do - 2 order lines = 2 rows

Comment: I took it out because the results were the same

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the criteria about which row should be preferred when duplicate value for `customers_customer_id` column is met. Depending on the sample input/output values I presume it will be the row with greater quantity. For this aim, use `row_number()` analytic function :

```
select customers_customer_id, product_product_id, quantity, order_date from
(
select o.customers_customer_id, oi.product_product_id, 
       oi.quantity, o.order_date,
       row_number() over (partition by o.customers_customer_id order by oi.quantity desc) as rn
  from orders o
  join order_item oi on oi.orders_order_id=o.order_id
 where o.order_date = '12/31/2015' 
)
where rn = 1
```